# ffplay compilation with a custom header

Tags: c++, c, compilation, compiler-errors, ffmpeg

I would like to re-compile ffplay with a custom header and a library (which is libOSC)

Could anyone tell me how to pass the library to the linker in the makefile

I get the following error:  http://pastebin.com/1Z3SiJjq

libOSC has been compiled and the libOSC.a file is in the libOSC source folder

I could successfully compile a test program implementing the testoscheader.h (my custom header) with a testoscheader.c and compiling it with gcc

```
gcc -o testoscheader testoscheader.c  htmsocket.c ../libOSC/libOSC.a
```

The htmsocket.c htmsocket.h can be found here http://archive.cnmat.berkeley.edu/OSC/src/sendOSC/

libosc can be found here http://archive.cnmat.berkeley.edu/OSC/src/libOSC/

Could anyone help me compile ffplay with the header

**Update::**

There were errors I could get rid of but this one is puzzling:

```
In file included from htmsocket.c:40:0,
                 from testoscheader.h:3,
                 from ffplay.c:47:
/usr/include/netinet/in.h: At top level:
/usr/include/netinet/in.h:368:17: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘__hostlong’
```

There is an include for "netinet/in.h" in ffplay.c and there are no errors when I compile it without my custom header. But it raises the error if I add my custom header

Can anyone point out the mistake here

Comment: I assume you're including new header files, maybe try flipping the order of which is included first?

Comment: @rogerdpack yes I tried but wasn't successfull ? I tried to put them in ffplay.d but doesn't work :/ any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THe problem was fixed by including netinet/in.h in htmsocket.c Hope this helps someone